# Puff pastry for cream horns

Tags: baking

I am making cream horns and I bake the puff pastry on the molds, let them cool and fill with cream. I freeze some empty for later, but they are not crispy. How to improve on that?

Comment: One big problem with freezing is that you'll get condensation when you defrost them ... but even with that, with frozen bread products you usually have to par-cook them, then finish baking them in the oven to defrost

Answer (score 6):

You can freeze them after baking and then refresh them by letting them defrost all the way and then re-baking them for a few minutes. This gets back some of the crispiness but it won't be as good as freshly baked.